# Custom user model to firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I have an AuthService class that has the following code

```
UserData _userDetFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    if (user != null) {
      return UserData(uid: user.uid);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Stream<UserData> get userData {
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map(_userDetFromFirebaseUser);
  }
```

And I used StreamProvider from the flutter provider package

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<UserData>.value(
      value: AuthService().userData,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: HomeController(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

It is all working well but the problem is that I want to add custom variables to the UserData model and get it through the provider and I don't know how to to do it. can You please help me?

the usermodel goes like this

```
class UserData {
  final String uid;
  String name;
  String phoneNumber;

  UserData({this.uid});
}
```

also: I tried calling `Provider.of` method and adding the fields in the app but then the app restarts the state is lost I want to save that state( the field variables in the model)I am new to Provider and state management so Please elaborate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is one of my next tasks. From my understanding so far, you create a root level folder in FireStore called /users and add for each user a document with the UID of the user as the document id.

Unfortunately I am still fighting other Firestore challenges before I can tell, whether this is already sufficient to get all the fields of that user document together with the returned User element upon login.

Comment: this is not what I meant. In the home controller, I want to check the name and some other fields whether empty and if, I need to show them another page to add the field. the problem is that when the app restarts the fields become empty and goes to the same page again and again because the state is not managed and I don't know how to manage/save the state

Comment: I still don't understand the question. When you saved the fields to FireStore and when you restarted the app, why should the fields be empty again when you read them from Firestore?!

Comment: I didn't use firestore. I was thinking of storing locally or in shared preference or something